# WCF: Updating Service Reference

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have an issue with updating (also tried deleting and adding) service reference of a modified WCF service in ASP.NET website project using "Add Service Reference" feature provided by VS 2010. It doesn't create the Reference.cs properly as it used to before changes. I verified my service configuration in the web.config, the endpoint seems to be properly configured with mexhttpbinding.

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Services.XyzService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Services.IXyzService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>

<behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
 </behavior>
```

Svc file also seems to be ok!!

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Services.XyzService"%>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried **"Add Service Refrence"** -->> **Update Service Reference**.

Comment: Yes, i meant the same when i said ' "Add Service Reference" feature provided by VS 2010', Thanks.

Comment: Use the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx), and 'Add Service' to your WCF service mex endpoint. It may report errors which are suppressed by Visual Studio.

Comment: anyways svcutil.exe did the work svcutil.exe /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 http://localhost:54651/XyzService.svc?wsdl